# Can someone explain me the output of this simple program in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

While debugging an issue in our codebase, I stumbled upon a problem which is quite similar to this sample problem below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int MAX = 100;
    int result = (v.size() - 1) / MAX;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the output of the program should be 0 but it's -171798692.

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: bogus results almost always indicate something uninitialised (like your vector :-) ).

Comment: As unsigned, `v.size() - 1` is a very big number...

Comment: @Dominique the vector is default constructed. Acutally I don't know how one can get a non-initialized `std::vector`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I guess you can (but you shouldn't) get one via `malloc()`.

Comment: @MikeCAT good to know that it is possible. I will now try to forget it again :P

Answer (score 8):

[`v.size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) returns an *unsigned* value `std::vector::size_type`. This is typically `size_t`.

Arithmetic in unsigned value wraps around, and `(v.size() - 1)` will be `0xffffffffffffffff` (18446744073709551615) if your `size_t` is 64-bit long.

Dividing this value with `100` yields `0x28F5C28F5C28F5C` (184467440737095516).

Then, this result is converted to `int`. If your `int` is 32-bit long and the conversion is done by simple truncation, the value will be `0xF5C28F5C`.

This value represents `-171798692`, which you got, in two's complement.

Comment: I was advised to cast the vector size to an integer to avoid such problems.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy Cast to a *signed* integer?

Comment: Yes, (int) v.size().

Comment: And C++20 guarantees the conversion way (the modulo) (whereas before, "any" value is correct).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `v.size() - 1`.

The [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) function returns an *unsigned* value. When you subtract `1` from unsigned `0` don't get `-1` but rather a very large value.

Then you convert this large unsigned value back into a *signed* integer type which could turn it negative.

Not only that, but on a 64-bit system it's likely that `size()` returns a 64 bit value, while `int` stays 32 bits, making you loose half the data.

Answer (score 0):

Vector `v` is empty, so `v.size()` is 0. Also `v.size()` is unsigned, so strange things happen when you subtract from that 0.

Comment: Well, it wraps around. This is not UB, but to be expected, right?

Comment: this is only "strange" when you ignore what actually happens. An answer to the question should explain what actually happens.

Comment: btw "ignore" in the sense of "don't know"/"are not aware of", no offense intended.